I cannot connect to my Cloud SQL instance via my Golang app in Cloud Run: "hostname resolving error: no such host"
Here are the technologies I am using:

Terraform
Golang + pgx/v5/pgxpool
Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL)
Cloud Run
Cloud Build

I have provisioned my PostgeSQL instance like so:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "db_name" {
  secret  = "db_name"
  version = "latest"
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "db_password" {
  secret  = "db_password"
  version = "latest"
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "db_user" {
  secret  = "db_user"
  version = "latest"
}

locals {
  db_name     = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.db_name.secret_data
  db_password = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.db_password.secret_data
  db_user     = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.db_user.secret_data
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "default" {
  name             = "postgres-pvp-instance-name"
  region           = var.region
  database_version = "POSTGRES_15"
  root_password    = local.db_password

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    password_validation_policy {
      min_length                  = 6
      reuse_interval              = 2
      disallow_username_substring = true
      password_change_interval    = "30s"
      enable_password_policy      = true
    }

    database_flags {
      name  = "cloudsql.iam_authentication"
      value = "on"
    }
  }

  deletion_protection = false
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "cloud-sql-postgres-sa"
  display_name = "Cloud SQL for Postgres Service Account"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "service_account_cloud_sql_client_binding" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/cloudsql.client"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "service_account_cloud_sql_instance_user_binding" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
  ]
}

resource "google_sql_user" "iam_service_account_user" {
  name     = trimsuffix(google_service_account.service_account.email, ".gserviceaccount.com")
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.default.name
  type     = "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
}

resource "google_sql_database" "default" {
  name     = local.db_name
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.default.name
}

And now, my Cloud Run:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

resource "google_service_account" "cloud_run" {
  account_id   = "cloud-run-sa"
  display_name = "Cloud Run Service Account"
  project      = var.project_id
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "cloud_run_artifact_registry" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/artifactregistry.reader"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloud_run.email}"
  ]
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "cloud_sql_client" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/cloudsql.client"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.cloud_run.email}"
  ]
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "db_name" {
  secret  = "db_name"
  version = "latest"
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "db_password" {
  secret  = "db_password"
  version = "latest"
}

data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "db_user" {
  secret  = "db_user"
  version = "latest"
}

locals {
  db_name     = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.db_name.secret_data
  db_password = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.db_password.secret_data
  db_user     = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.db_user.secret_data
}

resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "default" {
  name     = var.cloud_run_service_name
  location = var.region

  client = "terraform"

  template {
    containers {
      image = "${var.repository_url}/${var.image_name}:latest"

      ports {
        container_port = var.app_port
      }

      volume_mounts {
        mount_path = "/cloudsql"
        name       = "cloudsql"
      }

      resources {
        limits = {
          memory = "512Mi"
          cpu    = "1"
        }
      }
      env {
        name  = "DB_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
        value = var.db_instance_connection_name
      }

      env {
        name  = "DB_HOST"
        value = var.db_host
      }

      env {
        name  = "APP_PORT"
        value = var.app_port
      }

      env {
        name  = "DB_DATABASE"
        value = local.db_name
      }

      env {
        name  = "DB_USERNAME"
        value = local.db_user
      }
    }

    volumes {
      name = "cloudsql"
      cloud_sql_instance {
        instances = [var.db_instance_connection_name]
      }
    }

  }

  traffic {
    type    = "TRAFFIC_TARGET_ALLOCATION_TYPE_LATEST"
    percent = 100
  }
}

# Grant public access to the Cloud Run service
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service_iam_member" "public" {
  name     = google_cloud_run_v2_service.default.name
  location = google_cloud_run_v2_service.default.location
  project  = var.project_id
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}

Providing that the above is all correct, I attempt to connect in my Golang API like so:
func connectToDb() (*pgxpool.Pool, error) {
    appConfig := utils.GetConfig()
    l := utils.GetLogger()

    // Configure the driver to connect to the database
    l.Info().Msgf("Connecting to database: %s", appConfig.DatabaseName)
    l.Info().Msgf("Connection Name: %s", appConfig.DbInstanceConnectionName)
    l.Info().Msgf("Database User: %s", appConfig.DatabaseUser)

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=\"\" dbname=%s sslmode=disable", appConfig.DbInstanceConnectionName, appConfig.DatabaseUser, appConfig.DatabaseName)
    config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(dsn)
    if err != nil {
        l.Err(err).Msg("Failed to parse config")
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create a new dialer with any options
    d, err := cloudsqlconn.NewDialer(context.Background(), cloudsqlconn.WithIAMAuthN())
    if err != nil {
        l.Err(err).Msg("Failed to create dialer")
        return nil, err
    }

    // Tell the driver to use the Cloud SQL Go Connector to create connections
    config.ConnConfig.DialFunc = func(ctx context.Context, _ string, instance string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return d.Dial(ctx, appConfig.DbInstanceConnectionName)
    }

    // Interact with the driver directly as you normally would
    pool, err := pgxpool.NewWithConfig(context.Background(), config)
    if err != nil {
        l.Err(err).Msg("Failed to connect to database")
        return nil, err
    }

    err = pool.Ping(context.Background()) // THIS FAILS!!!
    if err != nil {
        l.Err(err).Msg("Failed to ping database")
        return nil, err
    }

    l.Info().Msgf("Connected to database")

    return pool, nil
}

It errors when attempting to ping.
I can confirm:

The database connection name is there in the app (projected:region:instance-name)
So is the the database user (cloud-run-sa@temp-myapp-1.iam)
I have followed Google's pgxpool example - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/blob/main/README.md#using-the-dialer-with-pgx

I feel something must be wrong with my Terraform setup, but I cannot see what is is.
The error is:

hostname resolving error: lookup {projected:region:instance-name}: no
such host

I can also see in Cloud Build/Cloud Run:

Step #2: Setting IAM Policy.........warning Step #2: Creating
Revision...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed
Step #2: Deployment failed Step #2:   Setting IAM policy failed, try
"gcloud beta run services add-iam-policy-binding --region=us-central1
--member=allUsers --role=roles/run.invoker opacitool-cloud-run-service" Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy)
Revision 'myapp-cloud-run-service-00031-nvh' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

But I have ran the gcloud command it suggests and it has no effect.

It seems like you have a configuration issue somewhere. First off, if you are using the Cloud SQL Go Connector you do not need any volume mounts (that is for the Cloud SQL Proxy which is a direct substitution of the Go Connector).

No such host points at the instance connection name probably being misconfigure, I would double check your appConfig.DbInstanceConnectionName. It should be in the form of PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME for your Cloud SQL instance. Probably worth having your terraform configure this as a variable via var.project_id:var.region:google_sql_database_instance.default.name

Thank you for your help @JackWotherspoon - I can confirm the DbInstanceConnectionName is there. I saw elsewhere, someone prefixed the host with a "/cloudsql/". I have done that, and now the error has changed to FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user \"cloud-sql-postgres-sa@temp-project-1.iam\"

If you're using the Go Connector, you should set "localhost" as the host name here:
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=localhost user=%s password=\"\" dbname=%s sslmode=disable", appConfig.DatabaseUser, appConfig.DatabaseName)

Then when the Go Connector dials your instance, it will resolve the correct hostname from the instance connection name.
Meanwhile, Cloud Run's built-in Cloud SQL integration doesn't support IAM authentication. But if you're already using the Go Connector, there's no need to rely on that integration anyway (or configure a unix socket with /cloudsql prefix).
